# How to use httpclient or HttpURLConnection to call jersey rest service with List @FormParam

Tags: android, jersey, httprequest, httpurlconnection, bad-request

i am trying to call a jersey service from android

```
@POST
@Path("/share")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response shareProgramVideo(@FormParam("from")Integer from, @FormParam("to")List<Integer> to,@FormParam("programIds")List<Integer> programIds)
```

the service works fine with html form

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>REST with Forms</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <form method="post" action="../dataService/rest/secure/program/share">

             from: <input type="text" name="from" id="from" /><br />

             to 1: <input type="text" name="to" id="to" /><br />
             to 2: <input type="text" name="to" id="to" /><br />

             programIds 1: <input type="text" name="programIds" id="programIds" /><br />
             programIds 2: <input type="text" name="programIds" id="programIds" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am using android and HttpRequest library  (https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)
but its give me 400 bad request error

```
     List<Integer> programs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
programs.add(1);
programs.add(2);

List<Integer> to = new ArrayList<Integer>();
to.add(1);
to.add(2);

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("from", 1);
data.put("to", to);
data.put("programIds", programs);

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.post(url)
        .basic(WebServiceConfig.ADMIN, WebServiceConfig.ADMIN_PSW).contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .acceptJson().form(data);

if (request.created() || request.ok()) {

    return true;

} else {

    Log.e("CreateUserProgramTask",
            "request.code()=" + request.code() + "request.body()="
                    + request.body());

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you are using but I think the problem could be in the way you're creating the 'programs' and 'to' params:

```
List<Integer> programs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
programs.add(1);
programs.add(2);

List<Integer> to = new ArrayList<Integer>();
to.add(1);
to.add(2);

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("from", 1);
data.put("to", to);
data.put("programIds", programs);
```

It seems the library is simply doing a toString() call in the Lists, but I think you should serialize as:

```
programs = "program1,program2"
to = "to1,to2"
```

I think this is not what is beins writen in the data Map